# How to check if a radio button in each group is checked in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

Multiple groups or radio buttons

```
<h1>Question 1</h1>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="false" />
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="true" /> 

<h1>Question 2</h1>
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="false" />
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="true" />
```

How can I check in jQuery that a radio button in each group is checked?

Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
var all_answered = true;
$("input:radio").each(function(){
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  if($("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked").length == 0)
  {
    all_answered = false;
  }
});
alert(all_answered);
```

That way you do not need to rely on sibling or parent tags. If your radio buttons are mixed up with whatever tag, it'll still work. You can [play around with it](http://jsfiddle.net/EGMdK/).

Comment: Yes, indeed the radio buttons were mixed up with other tags. But your solution worked. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through each question (`<h1>`) and looking through it's answers using [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) with [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to see if there any [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) ones, like this:

```
var noAns = $("h1").filter(function() {
              return $(this).nextUntil("h1").filter(":checked").length == 0;
            });
```

This would return all the questions with no radio selected for them, you could check the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) of that if you wanted to see if *any* don't have answers, for example:

```
if(noAns.length > 0) { 
  alert(noAns.length + " question(s) don't have answers!"); 
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hxzcJ/).

---

You can also extend this a bit, for example highlighting the questions that were missed:

```
if(noAns.css({ color: "red" }).length > 0) {
```

and use `$("h1").css({ color: "" })` to clear it the next round, [you can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hxzcJ/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each radio groups with a `form` or a `div` :

```
<div id="question1">
    <h1>Question 1</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="false" />
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="true" />
</div>

<div id="question2">
    <h1>Question 2</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="false" />
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="true" />
</div>
```

Then in jQuery:

```
if ($('#question1 input[type=radio]:checked')[0] != undefined && $('#question2 input[type=radio]:checked')[0] != undefined) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted the answer by "GG."  However, you don't need to change the 
HTML.

Just select by [name] (which should be unique):

```
if ($("input[name='radio1']:checked")[0] != undefined && 
    $("input[name='radio2']:checked")[0] != undefined) {
  ...
}
```