# How do I check to make sure all my input:radio elements have a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working on a form, and I've got a code that works for validating radio fields. However I plan on having many, MANY radio fields and I feel that my current method, which names each radio field individually, to be a bit tedious. I feel there must be a way I can simply select all of them to make sure they've all been checked before processing the form.

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxsdqy9o/)

**Current jQuery**

```
$("form").on("keyup change", function(){

food = $(":checked[name=food]");
color = $(":checked[name=color]");

if (food.val() == "" || food.val() == undefined || 
   color.val() == "" || color.val() == undefined){

//Do stuff

} else {

//Do other stuff

}
});
```

**jQuery I'm trying**

```
$("form").on("keyup change", function(){

radio_req = $(".required:checked[type=radio]");

if ( radio_req == "" || radio_req == undefined ) {

//Do stuff

} else {

//Do other stuff

}
});
```

With the 2nd one, I'm trying to see if I can just add a class of **required** to all my radio fields, and then just see if any `.required` radio buttons are left unselected/undefined. I feel there has to be a way for this to work. Am I on the right track? I feel like I'm just not selecting this right.

Comment: What about setting a default value?  You can't unselect a radio button.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553197/how-to-check-if-a-radio-button-in-each-group-is-checked-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxsdqy9o/4/), check it !
I hope it will solve your problem.

You can test the snippet under.
This is the part i modified :

```js
var checker = function(){    

var checked = $.unique($(".required:checked[type=radio]").map(function(){
    return  this.name;
}));
var not_checked = $.unique($(".required:not(:checked)[type=radio]").map(function(){
    return  this.name;
}));

if (checked.length !== not_checked.length){

    $("#submit").prop("disabled", true).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    $(".submit").text("* All fields must be completed and contain valid entries before submitting.");


} else {

$("#submit").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    $(".submit").text("");
}   
};
$("form").on("keyup change", checker);
checker();
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  // for each Question we have 3 choices:
  // so when we answer we have 1 checked and 2 unchecked
 
  // we loop over question
  // we fill 2 arrays(checked, unchecked) 
  // with names of radio 
  
  // for each question we will have something like that
  // Question 1 : food
  // checked = ['food']; notchecked = ['food','food']
  // we make them unique ! it becomes
  // checked = ['food']; notchecked = ['food'];
  // we know now that the First question have been answered
  
  // we loop over all question :
  // checked = ['food'] , notchecked = ['food' , 'color' , 'town' , 'country' , 'car']
  
  // we wait for checking !
  // let answer Qestion 2
  // checked = ['food' , 'color] , notchecked = ['food' , 'color' , 'town' , 'country' , 'car']
  // etc etc . . . 
  
  // when checked.length === notchecked.length => we have an answer for all question
  
var checker = function(){    

    var checked = $.unique(
      $(".required:checked[type=radio]").map(function(){
        return  this.name;
      })
    );
 var not_checked = $.unique(
      $(".required:not(:checked)[type=radio]").map(function(){
        return  this.name;
      })
    );
 
    if (checked.length !== not_checked.length){
    
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", true).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  $(".submit").text("* All fields must be completed and contain valid entries before submitting.");
 

    } else {
  
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  $(".submit").text("");
    }   
};
$("form").on("keyup change", checker);
checker();
    
});
```

```css
input {
    margin: 7px;
}

.valid {
    background-color: green;
    border: 3px solid darkgreen;
    color: white;
}

.invalid {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 3px solid darkgrey;
    color: black;
}

.error {
    color: red;
}

#submit {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 130px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  
  <br>Which of the following do you like the most?
  <br>
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="food" value="pizza">Pizza
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="food" value="burgers">Burgers
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="food" value="Salads">Salads
  <br>
  <br>Which of the following colors do you like the most?
  <br>
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="color" value="red">Red
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="color" value="blue">Blue
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="color" value="yellow">Yellow 
  <br>
  <br>Which of the following town do you like the most?
  <br>
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="town" value="red">New York
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="town" value="blue">Miami
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="town" value="yellow">Las Vegas 
  <br>
  <br>Which of the following country do you like the most?
  <br>
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="country" value="red">USA
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="country" value="blue">Canada
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="country" value="yellow">Chili
  <br>
  <br>Which of the following car do you like the most?
  <br>
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="car" value="red">Ferrari
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="car" value="blue">Dodge
  <input type="radio" class="required" name="car" value="yellow">Chevrolet

  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" class="invalid">
  <span class="submit error"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm, this appears to be working. I don't have time to seriously take a look at this thing right now. I want to make sure I completely understand what's going on here first. But this might just do it!

Comment: i make 2 array one with all checked and one not checked, make them unique and compare the length if they are equals so all are checked

Comment: ok, I see the two variables checking for unique checked and non-checked buttons. and I think I kinda understand the whole .map() thing (is return this.name building the arrays?). But I don't understand how the 2 arrays are supposed to match. At the end when it's all filled out, aren't checked radio buttons supposed to be 2 (in this case) and unchecked 0? How are they matching?

Comment: You have at first a list of radio for each question, imagine for only one question having as name = 'q1' : 2 or more response possible (radio), say 3. if nothing is checked we have `checked : null` and `not checked : q1 , q1 , q1` making it unique become `checked : null` `not checked : q1` now if we check we have  `not checked : q1` but `checked : q1` we have only 1 question so checked.length === not_checked.length and all is done !

Comment: i add some comments /explanation in my code snippet !

Comment: ok, so if I understand this, the arrays basically kick back a number corresponding to the selective criteria: How many boxes are checked vs how many could POSSIBLY be checked. Thus when both sides are equal, then all answers have been checked. Right? I think I got it! And since the selector does check against the `.required` class, that means if there is a radio button that I don't NEED answered, I could leave out the `.required` class and it wouldn't be included in the arrays, right?

Comment: one last question: is `return this.name;` an official shorthand version of `return $(this).attr("name");` ?

Comment: it you prefer you can use `$(this).attr("name");` it is just the jQuery way Vs pure Javascript way ! and yes for your previous question `.required` is  a good way to filter between those we use ant the others !

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all the radio buttons that have a name attribute `:radio[name]` in combination with an array, say `examined`, that helps you skip buttons that have already been checked. This should be work irrespective of how many sets of radio buttons there are in you form.

```
$('form').on('input change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var all_selected = true;
    var examined = [];
    $(':radio[name]').each(function() {
        if( examined.indexOf( this.name ) === -1 ) {
            examined.push( this.name );
            if( !$(':radio:checked[name=' + this.name + ']').length ) {
                all_selected = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    if( all_selected ) {
        //DO STUFF
    } else {
        //DO OTHER STUFF
    }
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('form').on('input change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var all_selected = true;
        var examined = [];
        $(':radio[name]').each(function() {
            if( examined.indexOf( this.name ) === -1 ) {
                examined.push( this.name );
                if( !$(':radio:checked[name=' + this.name + ']').length ) {
                    all_selected = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        if( all_selected ) {
            //DO STUFF
            console.log( 'All parts completed' );
        } else {
            //DO OTHER STUFF
            console.log( 'Form not complete' );
        }
    });
});
```

```css
input {
    margin: 7px;
}

.valid {
    background-color: green;
    border: 3px solid darkgreen;
    color: white;
}

.invalid {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 3px solid darkgrey;
    color: black;
}

.error {
    color: red;
}

#submit {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 130px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    Which of the following do you like the most?<br>
    <input type="radio" class="required" name="food" value="pizza">Pizza
    <input type="radio" class="required" name="food" value="burgers">Burgers
    <input type="radio" class="required" name="food" value="Salads">Salads <br><br>
        
    Which of the following colors do you like the most?<br>
    <input type="radio" class="required" name="color" value="red">Red
    <input type="radio" class="required" name="color" value="blue">Blue
    <input type="radio" class="required" name="color" value="yellow">Yellow
        
    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="invalid">
        <span class="submit error"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Just change the event from `submit` to `input change` and the snippet should work to your liking.