# Check for selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553197/how-to-check-if-a-radio-button-in-each-group-is-checked-in-jquery) to see what radio buttons I've checked and what I haven't but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function isEmpty() {
    $('#main_form').find('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
      var name = $(this).attr("name");
      if ($('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]:checked').val() === 'undefined') {
        $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]:checked').parents('.form_field').find('.form_label').addClass('not_valid');
      }
    });
  }

  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isEmpty();
  })
});
```

```css
.form_label.not_valid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main_form">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="form_field radio_buttons">
        <th class="form_label">Your product</th>
        <td colspan="5">
          <input type="radio" name="your_product" id="your_product_1" value="Goods">
          <label class="label-style" for="your_product_1">Goods</label>
          <input type="radio" name="your_product" id="your_product_2" value="In-between/both">
          <label class="label-style" for="your_product_2">In-between/both</label>
          <input type="radio" name="your_product" id="your_product_3" value="Services">
          <label class="label-style" for="your_product_3">Services</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="form_field radio_buttons">
        <th class="form_label">Clients</th>
        <td colspan="5">
          <input type="radio" name="clients" id="clients_1" value="Businesses">
          <label class="label-style" for="clients_1">Businesses</label>
          <input type="radio" name="clients" id="clients_2" value="In-between/both">
          <label class="label-style" for="clients_2">In-between/both</label>
          <input type="radio" name="clients" id="clients_3" value="Customers">
          <label class="label-style" for="clients_3">Customers</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
<a href="#">click</a>
```

When I do a `console.log($('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]:checked').val())` I get out, if I've checked the button the value of the group (3 times repeated), and undefined (3 times), if I don't select anything I get 6 times undefined. So if my logic is correct my labels should get the class `not_valid` and turn red. But I must be doing something wrong, my guess is something with the if condition. I just can't figure out what I'm missing here.

I want to make label red if the radio button group isn't selected.

Comment: I guess this `=== 'undefined'` is not checking what you expect (undefined value, not a string), try `=== undefined`

Comment: Better use `typeof $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]:checked').val() === 'undefined'`, Unless you have a radio with value `'undefined'`, your current if condition will never be true.

Comment: `typeof` is useful when you don't want to throw a ReferenceError, it's not the case

Comment: @Hacketo I tried just with `undefined`, no luck :\ I have no value `'undefined'`, I'll see what the `typeof` gives me.

Comment: You should use `$('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]').is(':checked')` instead of `$('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]:checked')`.

Comment: Another point: If `$('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]:checked')` gives `undefined`, you should not try to find its parent, just use `$('input:radio[name="' + name + '"])`

Comment: @KittMedia this works, but will give red label to checked button, I just need to reverse the is to not :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the comments:

1. `$('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]:checked').val() === 'undefined'` should be changed to `$('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]').is(':checked')` or something else. Currently it'll enter only if your checked radio have a value `'undefined'`.
2. As you want to check there's no checked value given that name, and alter the class of its parents, you should use `$('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]')`, without that `:checked`, which makes the result an empty jquery object.

You can also do that all in by `toggleClass`, [demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zuwofu08/), by using these, if you check the not valid groups, you are able to remove the invalid class by click that check button again.

```
// Get name
var name = $(this).attr("name");
// Get ref so we don't need to retrieve it twice.
var $targets = $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]');
//Find their parents, and toggle the class by check if the elements are checked or not.
$targets.parents('.form_field').find('.form_label').toggleClass('not_valid', !$targets.is(':checked'));
```

Altered origin code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function isEmpty() {
    $('#main_form').find('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
      var name = $(this).attr("name");
      
      // Check if the there's any radio with given name is checked.
      if (!$('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]').is(':checked')) {
        $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]').parents('.form_field').find('.form_label').addClass('not_valid');
      }
    });
  }

  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isEmpty();
  })
});
```

```css
.form_label.not_valid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main_form">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="form_field radio_buttons">
        <th class="form_label">Your product</th>
        <td colspan="5">
          <input type="radio" name="your_product" id="your_product_1" value="Goods">
          <label class="label-style" for="your_product_1">Goods</label>
          <input type="radio" name="your_product" id="your_product_2" value="In-between/both">
          <label class="label-style" for="your_product_2">In-between/both</label>
          <input type="radio" name="your_product" id="your_product_3" value="Services">
          <label class="label-style" for="your_product_3">Services</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="form_field radio_buttons">
        <th class="form_label">Clients</th>
        <td colspan="5">
          <input type="radio" name="clients" id="clients_1" value="Businesses">
          <label class="label-style" for="clients_1">Businesses</label>
          <input type="radio" name="clients" id="clients_2" value="In-between/both">
          <label class="label-style" for="clients_2">In-between/both</label>
          <input type="radio" name="clients" id="clients_3" value="Customers">
          <label class="label-style" for="clients_3">Customers</label>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
<a href="#">click</a>
```

Comment: This is essentially it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      function isEmpty() {
        $('#main_form').find('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
          var name = $(this).attr("name");

          if ($('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]').is(":not(:checked)")) {

            $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]').parents('.form_field').find('.form_label').addClass('not_valid');
          }
        });
      }
  $("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  isEmpty();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function isEmpty() {
    $('#main_form').find('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
      var name = $(this).attr("name");
      console.log(name, $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]').is(":checked"))
      if (!$('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]').is(":checked")) {
        console.log(name, "Error");
        $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]').parents('.form_field').find('.form_label').addClass('not_valid');
      }
      else{
        $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]').parents('.form_field').find('.form_label').removeClass('not_valid');
      }
    });
  }

  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isEmpty();
  })
});
```

```css
.not_valid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main_form">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="form_field radio_buttons">
        <th class="form_label">Your product</th>
        <td colspan="5">
          <input type="radio" name="your_product" id="your_product_1" value="Goods">
          <label class="label-style" for="your_product_1">Goods</label>
          <input type="radio" name="your_product" id="your_product_2" value="In-between/both">
          <label class="label-style" for="your_product_2">In-between/both</label>
          <input type="radio" name="your_product" id="your_product_3" value="Services">
          <label class="label-style" for="your_product_3">Services</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="form_field radio_buttons">
        <th class="form_label">Clients</th>
        <td colspan="5">
          <input type="radio" name="clients" id="clients_1" value="Businesses">
          <label class="label-style" for="clients_1">Businesses</label>
          <input type="radio" name="clients" id="clients_2" value="In-between/both">
          <label class="label-style" for="clients_2">In-between/both</label>
          <input type="radio" name="clients" id="clients_3" value="Customers">
          <label class="label-style" for="clients_3">Customers</label>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
<a href="#">click</a>
```