# how to check whether all radio and range selected or not before clicking submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to check whether all radio button checked or not before clicking the submit button. i want to know how to do these things in JQUERY. 
let me know the answer

HTML FILE:

```
              <div class="col datepicker">
                  <p class="question">1. what is birth date ?</p>
                  <input type="date" value="select date">
                  <span class="error">Must pick date</span>
              </div>

              <div class="col Dragger">
                  <p class="question">2. how much you like us?</p>
                  <div class="range range-positive range-background-dark"> 
                        <input type="range" name="volume" min="{{range.min}}" max="{{range.max}}" value="{{range.value}}" ng-change="sliding(range.value)" ng-model="range.value">                
                  </div>
                  <ul>
                        <li><strong>Unlikely</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>{{range.result}}</strong></li>
                        <li><strong>Verylikely</strong></li>
                  </ul> 
              </div>

              <div class="col smileyrating">
                  <p class="question">3. How was your visit ?</p>
                  <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="1" id="good" class="input-hidden" required />
                  <label for="good">
                      <img class="good" src="img/good.png">
                  </label>

                  <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="3" id="ok" class="input-hidden" required />
                  <label for="ok">
                      <img class="ok" src="img/Okay.png">
                  </label>

                  <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="5" id="bad" class="input-hidden" required />
                  <label for="bad">
                      <img class="bad" src="img/bad.png">
                  </label>
              </div>

              <div class="col selectTable">
                  <p class="question">4.are you willing to travel?</p>
                  <table>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="check" id="yes"  class="input-hidden" value="0"  required="">
                        <label for="yes">Yes</label></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="check" id="no"  class="input-hidden" value="1"  required="">
                        <label for="no">No</label></td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>

              <div class="col matrixTable">
                  <p class="question">4.how you maintain </p>
                  <table> 
                      <tr><th><h5>Economic</h5></th></tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Ecomomic"  value="0"><br><span>strong</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Ecomomic"  value="1"><br><span>verystrong</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Ecomomic"  value="2"><br><span>strong</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Ecomomic"  value="3"><br><span>veryweek</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Ecomomic"  value="4"><br><span>notsure</span></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr><th><h5>Healthcare</h5></th></tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Healthcare"  value="0"><br><span>strong</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Healthcare"  value="1"><br><span>verystrong</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Healthcare"  value="2"><br><span>strong</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Healthcare"  value="3"><br><span>veryweek</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Healthcare"  value="4"><br><span>veryweek</span></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr><th><h5>Immigration</h5></th></tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Immigration"  value="0"><br><span>strong</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Immigration"  value="1"><br><span>verystrong</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Immigration"  value="2"><br><span>strong</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Immigration"  value="3"><br><span>veryweek</span></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="Immigration"  value="4"><br><span>veryweek</span></td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>

              <div class="col thumbrating">
                  <p class="question">5. How was your visit ?</p>
                  <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="1" id="like" class="input-hidden" required />
                  <label for="like">
                      <img class="good" src="img/Like.png">
                  </label>

                  <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="3" id="unlike" class="input-hidden" required />
                  <label for="unlike">
                      <img class="bad" src="img/Unlike.png">
                  </label>
              </div>

            </div>
```

if possible please let me know how to do in angularjs also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553197/how-to-check-if-a-radio-button-in-each-group-is-checked-in-jquery

Comment: check first answer

Comment: thank you....i want to check range slider also wheather range is slide or not